# How to type object aggregation function in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, merge

According to some business rules, I created an aggregation function that I need to type correctly.

#### The function (JS):

It takes:

- Initial object.
- `n` objects.

```js
export function aggregateObjects(initialObject, ...newObjects) {
  const aggregate = (objectA, objectB) => {
    return Object.keys(objectB).reduce(
      (acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: [...(acc[key] ?? []), ...(objectB[key] ?? [])],
      }),
      objectA
    );
  };

  return newObjects.reduce(
    (aggregatedObjects, newObject) => aggregate(aggregatedObjects, newObject),
    initialObject
  );
}
```

#### How to use it (TypeScript):

Here is an example of two new objects passed to `aggregateObjects`, but it should work with 5, 10, ...

```
const initialObject = {
  a: [objectOfType1],
};

const newObject1 = {
  a: [objectOfType2],
  b: [objectOfType1],
};

const newObject2 = {
  c: [objectOfType1, objectOfType2],
};

const result = aggregateObjects(initialObject, [newObject1, newObject2]);
```

#### What we expect (TypeScript):

According to previous example, we expect this result:

- `a` should be typed as an array of `ObjectType1` or `ObjectType2`.
- `b` should be typed as an array of `ObjectType1`.
- `c` should be typed as an array of `ObjectType1` or `ObjectType2`.

```
type Result = {
  a: (ObjectType1 | ObjectType2)[];
  b: ObjectType1[];
  c: (ObjectType1 | ObjectType2)[];
};
```

#### What I tried (TypeScript):

Of course, it does not work:

- Internal `aggregate` seems OK (even if there's some issues related to spread).
- Outside, I didn't find a solution to correctly type return value.

Note that `CombineObjs` is a TS helper inspired from https://dev.to/svehla/typescript-how-to-deep-merge-170c

```
export function aggregateObjects<T extends object, U extends any[]>(
  initialObjects: T,
  ...newObjects: U
) {
  const aggregate = <A extends object, B extends object>(
    objectA: A,
    objectB: B
  ): CombineObjs<A, B> => {
    return (Object.keys(objectB) as Array<keyof B>).reduce(
      (acc, key) => ({
        ...acc,
        [key]: [
          // @ts-ignore
          ...(acc[key as keyof CombineObjs<A, B>] ?? []),
          // @ts-ignore
          ...(objectB[key] ?? []),
        ],
      }),
      objectA as unknown as CombineObjs<A, B>
    );
  };

  return newObjects.reduce(
    (aggregatedObjects, newObject) => aggregate(aggregatedObjects, newObject),
    initialObjects
  );
}
```

Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: Why should `c` be of type `ObjectType2[]` and not `(ObjectType1 | ObjectType2)[]`? It would be helpful if at least the JavaScript part was working before trying to help you with the typing.

Comment: It was a mistake; it's fixed now.

Comment: Also you mention "recursivity". But I don't see any recursive function call.

Comment: You're right: there's not recursion inside my implementation. I use a `CombineObjs` TS util taking only two generics, and I need to have it working on `n` generics. I didn't find a solution. Finally, the return type I want is a combine of multiple objects (but I can't use this type).

Comment: Is there some constraint to the `ObjectTypes`? Are they always supposed to be a flat object structure where the values are tuples? Or can they have an arbitrary shape? What would happen if `a: "123"`?

Comment: You are using the type `CombineObjs`. Is it the same as `DeepMergeTwoTypes` from the article or is it only *"inspired"* but different? If it is different, can you show us the implementation?

Comment: If you talk about root properties `a`, `b`, `c` (or any other), they always suppose to have a tuples value. However, these tuples can contain any type of value (here, `objectOfType1`, `objectOfType2`, but it could be a `string`, etc.).

Comment: Here is the implementation:
``type CombineObjs<T, U> = DeepMergeTwoTypes<T, U>;``

I use exactly `DeepMergeTwoTypes` generic type from the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the typing for the function.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
  (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;

function aggregateObjects<
  T extends Record<string, any[]
>[]>(objects: [...T]): { 
  [K in keyof UnionToIntersection<T[number]>]: (T[number] extends infer U ? 
    U extends Record<K, (infer V)[]> 
      ? V
      : never
    : never)[]
} {
    return {} as any
}
```

I did not see any reason for the `initialObject` to be a separate parameter, since it seems to be handled exactly like the other objects.

```
const initialObject = {
  a: ["objectOfType1"],
};

const newObject1 = {
  a: [23],
  b: ["objectOfType1"],
};

const newObject2 = {
  c: ["objectOfType1", 23],
};

const result = aggregateObjects([initialObject, newObject1, newObject2]);
// const result: {
//   a: (string | number)[];
//   b: string[];
//   c: (string | number)[];
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOU4EMA2B5ARgKwKbCwC8MA3gFAwwoBcMA2gEQi4FQYBmAKgJ4AOeAIyMAugBpyAXwDc5cqEiwweAO7Z8hQTBIUqtBgCYAzOMowsdJiw3tu-IaIky5C6DGVrWhA9rJnglsxetrwCwmIwxqbO8uBuAE54EACuaMTUAOYZiRkoUHjqbBAAFPQISKiYwREehZo1qnVQBiIAlLIA9B0wrrCJKWl0FF1U1HTF0PEIGTAAPu7JALZYePGt9CKd3VQWMJPTG1ujATATUFNgM-NgSytrh%20QjknJQ9jAAqojgXCAAkmD5eIQNhwcAAHneAD5tGZiu8YHgAB75MAAEwg1DAPBgAH5TgBrOjvVraaEANxAcFRMDoyjJqxJSJR6NOxUJ8DAHFWMF%20JKI5MpqJJeN%20NPceHp8Vk5A4yTAhFBYEy2TwuXyTQgYLMXARyLwaIxACUCCB4qiwftLhEUFiNuRIRtIcVrEVLAA6D1cNpDGBmegAaQ5MHxeB4IA4Hy%20YB%20-0BwIV4K49Buy1WIkhInGSZTdxEuuZGIQXPiH1xvtGpaZ%20pZxtAZrB-oixSL3IAaut0%20WK2XW2YK7SJas%202K6Qy7ZI-BXElBkvElaQJygMTaeFIgA)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time, I'm going to try that. I agree that it's not useful to provide separate initial object.

Comment: For information, here is my working version, with updated implementation types: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-spwu7a?file=index.ts